# JSF 2.2 not rendering or Getting content from the javaBean

Tags: java, javabeans, jsf-2.2, managed-bean

I am encountering a problem where nothing gets rendered on the browser.

I tried to do it in Intellij using Tomcat, and nope not working.

I tried NetBeans using GlassFish and it is not working neither.

TimeBean.java

```
package jsf2demo;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@Named(value = "timeBean")
@RequestScoped
public class TimeBean {
  public TimeBean() {
  }

  public String getTime() {
    return new java.util.Date().toString();
  }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

CurrentTime.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
  <h:head>
    <title>Display Current Time</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content ="60" />
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
    The current time is #{timeBean.time}
  </h:body>
</html>
```

And this is all I get(see attached pic on the link) 
https://imageshack.com/a/img923/4843/rpBfRZ.jpg

Comment: What could it be the problem? - Sorry for the mistakes but I meant content*

Comment: you can edit your questions. And if you use jag 2.0 the question can never be jsf 2.2 related. And did you do a view- source on the client? what did you see?

Comment: Well you are mapping the FacesServlet to `/faces/*` and trying to access a resource from `/` so it isn't being processed by JSF. Try changing the `<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` also, is that a typo: `<servlet-mappin g>` that space before the `g` on mapping ?

Comment: Thanks @Kukeltje, I am pretty new asking, I am usually end up finding answer or figuring out this myself. And this is what I get in the view-source: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img923/6381/eDT1er.jpg

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it says"The FacesServlet cannot have a url-pattern of /*. Please define a different url-pattern"  and yes @JorgeCampos that was a typo

Comment: sorry, my bad. change it to `<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>` without the dash. And try in your browser `..../CurrentTime.jsf` if it works I will provide you an answer.

Comment: Remove the patterns altogether in new JSF versions

Comment: @JorgeCampos I tried and nope, it will just say that the Build Failed, so if I don't have that part it will fail to build, same for what you said

Comment: Same occurs for what you said @Kukeltje

Comment: and @Kukeltje I actually noticed that it was using the JSF 2.2

Comment: But I also noticed that when I create a new project, and try to add the framework JSF 2.2 it does not allow me on NetBeans, I really do not understand why, as I have basically follow every single step in the book over and over and still not working....

Comment: I have tried to open it in another computer, reinstalling NetBeans, Intellij, reinstalling Tomcat, GlassFish, and nope the jsf is not rendering still...

Comment: Have you tried using *.xhtml for the url-pattern?

Comment: OMFG :O I swear I had tried it before! but with Intellij and not with net beans! Now it is working!!! Thank you so much @ChadNC!!!